# Creating record that belongs to 2 seperate tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to create a record that is associated with 2 tables but I cannot seem to get it to work.

> Parameters: {"name"=>"asdfasd", "upc"=>"243252353", "availableOn"=>"07/12/2020", "properties"=>[{"name"=>"material", "value"=>"jean"}], "send_datum"=>{"name"=>"asdfasd", "upc"=>"243252353", "availableOn"=>"07/12/2020", "properties"=>[{"name"=>"material", "value"=>"jean"}]}}

```
class SendDataController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

    def save
        product = Product.create(name:params[:name], upc:params[:upc].to_i, available_on:params[:availableon])

        x=0
        while x < params[:properties].length
            property = product.properties.create(name:params[:properties][x][:name])
            property.product_properties.create(value:params[:properties][x][:value])

            x += 1;
        end

    end    
end
```

This line is the one I cannot seam to get to work:

> property.product_properties.create(value:params[:properties][x][:value])

This is my first react on rails project and understanding table assoc. has been a real challenge but I am getting there.

Models:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :product_properties
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :properties
  has_many :product_properties
end

class ProductProperty < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :upc
      t.datetime :available_on

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProductProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :product_properties do |t|
      t.string :value

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddProductRefToProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :properties, :product, foreign_key: true
  end
end

class AddProductRefToProductProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :product_properties, :product, foreign_key: true
  end
end

class AddPropertiesRefToProductProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :product_properties, :property, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_09_24_163027) do

  create_table "product_properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "value"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "property_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_product_properties_on_product_id"
    t.index ["property_id"], name: "index_product_properties_on_property_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "upc"
    t.datetime "available_on"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_properties_on_product_id"
  end

end
```

**UPDATE::**
It is related to the fact that the product_property is getting the property_id from property but is not getting the product_id from the product.  How do I fix that?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!

Comment: Can you update the question with the params that appearin the server log when you submit the form?

Comment: @Pavan added those params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I had my associations set up incorrectly.  As @DavidAldridge pointed out I needed to link Property to Product through product property.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_properties
  has_many :properties, through: :product_properties
end

class ProductProperty < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property, required: false
  belongs_to :product, required: false
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_properties
  has_many :products, through: :product_properties
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_properties
end
```